# How to move Menus customizer section directly under Site Identity?

Tags: theme-customizer

Is it possible to change the priority of the Menus customizer section so that it is directly under the Site Identity section?

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: I was curious and just searched this site for [get_panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=get_panel) method and that seems to be the way to get and modify the panel instance. E.g. this question ["How to access the nav_menus panel with the customizer api?"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214293/how-to-access-the-nav-menus-panel-with-the-customizer-api) seems related. There @WestonRuter does change the priority of the *Menus* panel, but without applying `add_panel()` and using the `$wp_customize` instance as the input parameter in the `customize_register` callback. I just checked and it's in fact passed on, because of `do_action( 'customize_register', $this );` in `WP_Customize_Manager::wp_loaded()`. Previously I had looked at:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'register_controls' ) );
```

where:

```
/**
 * Register some default controls.
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 */
 public function register_controls() {
```

had no input parameter.

I've therefore adjusted the answer below by removing the `add_panel()` and by using the `$wp_customize` as input parameter for the `customize_register` callback, instead of `function() use ( &$wp_customize )`.

---

I dug through the Customizer classes and tested various things. This approach  seems to work:

```
/**
 * Change priority and title for the 'Menus' panel in the Customizer
 */
add_action( 'customize_register', function( \WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize )
{
    // Get the 'Menus' panel instance
    $mypanel = $wp_customize->get_panel( 'nav_menus');

    if( $mypanel instanceof \WP_Customize_Nav_Menus_Panel )
    {
        // Adjust to your needs:
        $mypanel ->priority = 21;    
        $mypanel ->title    = 'My Great Menus!';
    }

}, 12 );
```

<strike>but I've no idea how people do this in general or if it's the way to go ;-)</strike>

We use the priority of 21 here, since the *Site Identity* section has priority of 20.

In our case we have a panel, not section, but within the `WP_Customize_Manager::prepare_controls()` the sections and panels are combined and ordered by priority via `usort` and `WP_Customize_Manager::_cmp_priority()`.

Here we can see the changes:

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

We can make this more dynamic, by fetching the priority of the *Site Identity* section:

```
/**
 * Change priority and title for the 'Menus' panel in the Customizer
 */
add_action( 'customize_register', function( \WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize )
{
    // Get the 'Menus' panel instance
    $mypanel   = $wp_customize->get_panel( 'nav_menus' );

    // Get the 'Site Identity' section instance
    $mysection = $wp_customize->get_section( 'title_tagline' );

    if( 
            $mypanel instanceof \WP_Customize_Nav_Menus_Panel 
        &&  $mysection instanceof \WP_Customize_Section
    ) {
        // Adjust to your needs
        $mypanel->priority = $mysection->priority + 1;
        $mypanel->title    = 'My Great Menus!';    
    }

}, 12 );
```